# How to create a sequential count by group that excludes values that are in rows above

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

```
entry_id <- c(222,222,222,222,222,223,223,223,223,224,224,224,224,224,224,224)
id_1 <- c(2,4,3,5,1,3,1,4,2,6,3,7,2,1,9,5)
id_2 <- c(1,3,5,2,8,2,7,3,1,2,4,9,5,3,2,8)
df <- data.frame(entry_id,id_1,id_2)
```

For each `entry_id`, I want to create a sequential count of `id_1` values that do not appear in `id_2` rows above. If the `id_1` value does appear above it in `id_2` (for the same `entry_id`), then I want to mark it with `NA`. My result for this sample data would look like this:

```
df$result <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,1,2,3,NA,4,NA,NA)
```

My attempt at doing this looks like this. First, I add a `row_index`

```
df$row_index <- seq.int(nrow(df))
```

Then, I attempt to mark the ones that I want to count with a string, and mark the ones I don't want to count with `NA`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

```
df$result <- apply(df,1,function(x) ifelse(x["id_1"] %in% x["id_2"][1:x["row_index"] - 1],NA,"count_this"))
```

If I could get the above code to work, the next thing I would do is something like this:

```
df <- transform(df,result = ave(result, entry_id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(!is.na(x))))
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(entry_id) %>%
  mutate(
    m = match(id_1, id_2),
    m = (is.na(m) | m >= row_number()),
    r = if_else(m, cumsum(m), NA_integer_)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-m)
# # A tibble: 16 x 4
#    entry_id  id_1  id_2     r
#       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#  1      222     2     1     1
#  2      222     4     3     2
#  3      222     3     5    NA
#  4      222     5     2    NA
#  5      222     1     8    NA
#  6      223     3     2     1
#  7      223     1     7     2
#  8      223     4     3     3
#  9      223     2     1    NA
# 10      224     6     2     1
# 11      224     3     4     2
# 12      224     7     9     3
# 13      224     2     5    NA
# 14      224     1     3     4
# 15      224     9     2    NA
# 16      224     5     8    NA
```

---

Explanation, let's look at the last group:

```
x <- df[10:16,]

match(x$id_1, x$id_2)
# [1] NA  5 NA  1 NA  3  4
```

This returns the first index of a match, `NA` if not found. If `NA` then it is not found at all so should be counted. If a number that is greater than or equal to the position within this vector, then it first occurs later, so it should be counted. If a number and less than the position within the vector, then it should be `NA`.

From there, I create the conditional `m` (temp), which indicates what should be counted.

```
df %>%
  group_by(entry_id) %>%
  mutate(
    m = match(id_1, id_2),
    m = (is.na(m) | m >= row_number()),
    r = if_else(m, cumsum(m), NA_integer_)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 x 5
#    entry_id  id_1  id_2 m         r
#       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <int>
#  1      222     2     1 TRUE      1
#  2      222     4     3 TRUE      2
#  3      222     3     5 FALSE    NA
#  4      222     5     2 FALSE    NA
#  5      222     1     8 FALSE    NA
#  6      223     3     2 TRUE      1
#  7      223     1     7 TRUE      2
#  8      223     4     3 TRUE      3
#  9      223     2     1 FALSE    NA
# 10      224     6     2 TRUE      1
# 11      224     3     4 TRUE      2
# 12      224     7     9 TRUE      3
# 13      224     2     5 FALSE    NA
# 14      224     1     3 TRUE      4
# 15      224     9     2 FALSE    NA
# 16      224     5     8 FALSE    NA
```

From there, `cumsum(m)` keeps the count what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, I have over complicated this but one approach using base R

```
df$result1 <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$entry_id), function(x) {
        temp = sapply(1:nrow(x), function(y) !x[y, "id_1"] %in% x[1:y, "id_2"])
        ifelse(temp, cumsum(temp), NA)
}))

df
#   entry_id id_1 id_2 result result1
#1       222    2    1      1       1
#2       222    4    3      2       2
#3       222    3    5     NA      NA
#4       222    5    2     NA      NA
#5       222    1    8     NA      NA
#6       223    3    2      1       1
#7       223    1    7      2       2
#8       223    4    3      3       3
#9       223    2    1     NA      NA
#10      224    6    2      1       1
#11      224    3    4      2       2
#12      224    7    9      3       3
#13      224    2    5     NA      NA
#14      224    1    3      4       4
#15      224    9    2     NA      NA
#16      224    5    8     NA      NA
```

We `split` the dataframe by `entry_id` so every `entry_id` has got a separate dataframe. Then for each dataframe we loop over each row and check if `id_1` value at that row is present in `id_2` values in rows above. If we don't find the `id_1` values in `id_2` we increment the counter using `cumsum` or else just return `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function and then use split. Some looping probably cannot be avoided.

```
entry_id <- c(222,222,222,222,222,223,223,223,223,224,224,224,224,224,224,224)
id_1 <- c(2,4,3,5,1,3,1,4,2,6,3,7,2,1,9,5)
id_2 <- c(1,3,5,2,8,2,7,3,1,2,4,9,5,3,2,8)
df <- data.frame(entry_id,id_1,id_2)
df$result <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,1,2,3,NA,4,NA,NA)

my_check <- function(a, b) {
  flag <- rep(1, length(a))
  res  <- rep(0, length(a))
  for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    if (a[i] %in% b[1:max(1, i-1)]) {
      flag[i] <- 0
      res[i] <- NA
    } else {
      res[i] <- cumsum(flag)[i]
    }    
  }
  return(res)
}

df$result2 <- unlist(lapply(split(df[, c("id_1", "id_2")], df$entry_id),
                            function(x) my_check(x[[1]], x[[2]])))
df


#   entry_id id_1 id_2 result result2
#1       222    2    1      1       1
#2       222    4    3      2       2
#3       222    3    5     NA      NA
#4       222    5    2     NA      NA
#5       222    1    8     NA      NA
#6       223    3    2      1       1
#7       223    1    7      2       2
#8       223    4    3      3       3
#9       223    2    1     NA      NA
#10      224    6    2      1       1
#11      224    3    4      2       2
#12      224    7    9      3       3
#13      224    2    5     NA      NA
#14      224    1    3      4       4
#15      224    9    2     NA      NA
#16      224    5    8     NA      NA
```